# Functions with Character Array?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am really struggling with learning programming via C.  I seem to get the gist of things while going through the book's exercises but the second I try to implement something different it falls apart especially in regard to arrays.

I am making a simple game with a 2D character array. It should be 11x11.  I am trying to write a function to set each index of the array as a blank space ' ' to start.  My code compiles then I get a 'core dump' when I run it.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*-------- GLOBAL FUNCTIONS --------*/


// Clear the Screen
void clear()
{
    system("clear");    // For Linux/iOS
}


//----------   Creat Array(Game Board)

#define MAX 11 // Max number of characters in each row and column of array
char GameBoard[MAX][MAX];


// Clear Each Space in Array with Empty ("") Space
void ClearBoard(char GB[MAX][MAX])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        GameBoard[i][i] = ' ';
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++i)
        {
            GameBoard[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}



int main()
{


    ClearBoard(GameBoard);


return 0;
}
```

Any help towards understanding this better would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. If you run the program in a debugger it will stop when the crash happens, at the location of the crash. You can then examine the value of variables to help you understand what is wrong.

Comment: Also, here's some general tips: First of all don't use global variables if you can avoid it. In this case you can make `GameBoard` a local variable in the `main` function. That will lead to my second tip: In the `ClearBoard` function you don't use the argument passed to the function but the global variable. You should change that.

Comment: copy-paste error in inner `for`.

Answer (score 3):

your inner loop increments `i` until it is out of the array bounds

it should be `++j` and not `++i`

after `MAX+1` iterations of the inner loop you're trying to access memory which is not allocated and that is why you get your error.

also the line `GameBoard[i][i] = ' ';` is unnecessary since it is taken care of in the inner loop when `j == i`

Comment: Yes, I caught that finally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line

```
   for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++i)
```

to

```
   for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++j)
```

Comment: Yes, I totally missed that thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `++i` with `++j` in the line

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++i)
```

Comment: Yeah we needed a 4th answer saying that... :)

Comment: @Lundin when writing my answer, I cannot look at if other users answer too :)

Comment: That' what the "unreproducible/typo" close-vote is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 GameBoard[i][i] = ' ';
```

This line doesn't make any sense. Remove it.

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++i)
```

Should be `j++`.

Comment: Although pointless, what's the problem with initializing the leading diagonal twice?

Comment: @Useless The problem is that the line is useless. It fills no purpose and will only make the program slower.

Comment: Agreed, but it's not the cause of the core dump.

Comment: @Useless It could have been, if the x and y dimensions were different . Suppose the array was changed to `[10][5]`.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response.  Got it working great!  Im sure I will be back soon with this one.  Really Thanks.